# SQL Query - Displaying the same column twice under different conditions

Tags: sql

I am wondering if the following is possible. Say I have the following table:

**ID | NAME** 
 1 | John 
 2 | Bob 
 3 | John 
 4 | Bob

Is it possible to run a query that results in the following:

**NAME| ID1 | ID2** 
John    | 1    | 3 
Bob      | 2    | 4

*EDIT*

Sorry for the confusion. My question addresses instances where I need to handle the possibility of 2 duplicates for a large data set.

Comment: Are you saying that the query only NEEDS to handle the possibility of 2 duplicates, or just that your example has 2?

Comment: It only needs to handle the possibility of 2 duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming exactly 2 duplicates

```
SELECT 
   NAME, 
   MIN(ID) as ID1,
   MAX(ID) as ID2
FROM Table t
GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Note that the subquery screens out all names that don't have exactly two `id`s.

```
select name,min(id) as id1,max(id) as id2
from table
join(
    select name
    from table
    group by name
    having count(1)=2
)names
using(name)
group by name;
```

Comment: Not sure you need the join here.  also I'm close to a -1 for the natural join

Comment: Well, you can either do the join or add on a `where name in (select name from table group by name having count(1)=2)`. Honestly, the query optimizer usually abstracts that away.

Comment: I'm not sure he even needs to filter at all though, since he would just have two ids with identical values without it

Answer (score 1):

If there are exactly two rows with each name, then the following should work:

```
 SELECT a.name,
        a.id as id1,
        b.id as id2
 FROM the_table a 
   JOIN the_table b ON a.name = b.name AND a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: This will give duplicate rows since you don't check to see if the id values are identical

Comment: This would still return duplicates, you would see a John | 1 | 3 and John | 3 | 1, unless i'm mistaken :)